# How to programmatically know when pg_restore is Complete

Tags: python-3.x, pg-restore

I'm writing a Python script that will execute pg_restore.  Once the restore has completed, I would like the Python script to execute several CREATE and GRANT statements to create the DB users.

*I can't use pg_dumpall to add those to the dump, as I'm migrating from AWS and pg_dumpall isn't allowed.  So, I had to pull down the individual privileges and write a script using template/dictionary to do it for me.

**My question:  Is there a way for my Python script to check that the pg_restore command has completed, so that it can move to the next piece of the code?  Right now, as soon as the pg_restore is kicked off, it immediately returns with SUCCESS.  I haven't been able to find anything about this.  Usually, in SQL Server, I WAITFOR DELAY in a loop when I need to wait for something (usually JobAgent) to complete.

Comment: Hi All.  Just bumping this to the top.  Could someone please help me with this question?  I'm *really* stuck, and I've run out of ways to ask Google for help on this one.  Thank you

Comment: Hi All.  Bumping to the top again.  Does anyone know how my Python script can programatically tell when pg_dump has completed processing?  I use subprocess.Popen to execute the pg_dump command.  Is there another method that I could use to force it to pause until the command has completed?

Comment: It appears this has a much simpler solution than I thought it would.  I'm going to share my solution here, in case anyone else comes across this post with a similar question.  Instead of using subprocess.Popen to execute the pg_dump command, I needed to use subprocess.check_call.  In the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html), it explicitly says "Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete. If the return code was zero then return, otherwise raise CalledProcessError."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this as a comment above, but it's more visible as an answer.

It appears this has a much simpler solution than I thought it would. I'm going to share my solution here, in case anyone else comes across this post with a similar question. Instead of using subprocess.Popen to execute the pg_restore command, I needed to use subprocess.check_call. In the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html), it explicitly says for subprocess.check_call:

> "Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete. If the
>   return code was zero then return, otherwise raise CalledProcessError."

Once I added this to my Python script, it performed exactly like I had hoped - it paused until the pg_restore completed before moving to the next line of code.